# How do I show a circle when touched on android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an android app and I can't seem to find anywhere how to make a simple activity where a circle shows up when anywhere on the screen is touched. It doesn't have to link with the coordinates with the click, just a circle in the middle of the screen. I have the frameview and everything set up, I just need to figure out the circle class. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Touch events to get the touch points of x and y value.

[refer this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

use canvas to draw circle.

[refer this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial is kinda old](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/), but should get you most of the way there...

Comment: I used this one first. I just needed one circle that would show up in the middle of the screen whenever a finger was on the screen

Comment: @t3hcakeman So ignore the x.y locations for the touches, and just draw it in the middle of the screen?  I'm starting to think I'm missing the point though...

Comment: Will it go away once the click is released? And the point is for long shutter photography light drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a SurfaceView with a drawable at the place where screen is touched. 
Refer to this sample which does something similar

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/BouncingBalls.html